# ASP.NET + Entity Framework - обращение к базе данных из Use

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

добавляю контекст базы данных в сервисы. Могу обращаться к нему из app.MapGet(). Но перед этим я хочу обработать запрос через Use. Как обратиться к базе данных внутри Use?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<UserContext>();

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => { policy.WithOrigins("*"); });
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // Здесь должно быть обращение к БД

    await next.Invoke(context);
});


app.MapGet("/vk/main_info", async (int vk_user_id, UserContext database) =>
{
    // Тут дальнейшая обработка запроса
});
    

app.Run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаём класс мидлвари:

```
public class SomeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SomeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) => _next = next;

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, UserContext dbContext)
    {
        // use dbContext

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Подключаем его вместо `app.Use(...);`:

```
app.UseMiddleware<SomeMiddleware>();
```